# How to communicate with continuously running background service in Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-broadcast, android-location

In my project, there is a service that retrieves location of users. It continuously runs in background. I want to set location on my textview.
So, I have `ManinActivity` as follows:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    GPSTracker gps;
    double mylatitude, mylongitude;
    TextView txt_location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt_location = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.current_location);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }              
    }

    public void btn_remember_Clicked(View v)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,RememberActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void btn_show_places_Clicked(View v)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ShowPlacesActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);    
        }
    }
}
```

And my `LocationService` class is as follows:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LocationService extends Service
{
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "Hello World";
    private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;
    public LocationManager locationManager;
    public MyLocationListener listener;
    public Location previousBestLocation = null;
    
    Intent intent;    
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId)
    {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        listener = new MyLocationListener();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 4000, 0, listener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 4000, 0, listener);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
    
    protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
        if (currentBestLocation == null) {
            // A new location is always better than no location
            return true;
        }
    
        // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
        long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
        boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
        boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
        boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;
    
        // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location
        // because the user has likely moved
        if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
            return true;
            // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be worse
        } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
            return false;
        }
    
        // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
        int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
        boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
        boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
        boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;
    
        // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
        boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
                    currentBestLocation.getProvider());
    
        // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and accuracy
        if (isMoreAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate && isFromSameProvider) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    /** Checks whether two providers are the same */
    private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
        if (provider1 == null) {
            return provider2 == null;
        }
        return provider1.equals(provider2);
    }
            
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.v("STOP_SERVICE", "DONE");
        locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
    }
    
    public static Thread performOnBackgroundThread(final Runnable runnable) {
        final Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    runnable.run();
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.print(e);
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        return t;
    }
    
    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc) {
            Log.i("**************************************", "Location changed");
            if(isBetterLocation(loc, previousBestLocation)) {
                loc.getLatitude();
                loc.getLongitude();
                intent.putExtra("Latitude", loc.getLatitude());
                intent.putExtra("Longitude", loc.getLongitude());
                intent.putExtra("Provider", loc.getProvider());
                sendBroadcast(intent);        
            }
        }
    
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
            
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
            
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }
}
```

and I have `LocationBroadcast` class as follows:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class LocationBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        ctx.startService(new Intent(ctx, LocationService.class));
    }
}
```

I want to set location on textview `txt_location` in `MainActivity`. I do not know much about services and how we can communicate within Activity. How can I get latitude and longitude in MainActivity? Please help.

## Update:

I have just updated my code according to answers:

```
public class LocationService extends Service
{
    private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;
    public LocationManager locationManager;
    public MyLocationListener listener;
    public Location previousBestLocation = null;

    Intent i;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        i = new Intent("LOCATION_CHANGED");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId)
    {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        listener = new MyLocationListener();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 4000, 0, listener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 4000, 0, listener);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
        if (currentBestLocation == null) {
            // A new location is always better than no location
            return true;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
        long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
        boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
        boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
        boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

        // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location
        // because the user has likely moved
        if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
            return true;
            // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be worse
        } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
        int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
        boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
        boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
        boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

        // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
        boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
                currentBestLocation.getProvider());

        // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and accuracy
        if (isMoreAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate && isFromSameProvider) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /** Checks whether two providers are the same */
    private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
        if (provider1 == null) {
            return provider2 == null;
        }
        return provider1.equals(provider2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.v("STOP_SERVICE", "DONE");
        locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
    }

    public static Thread performOnBackgroundThread(final Runnable runnable) {
        final Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    runnable.run();
                } catch(Exception e) {
System.out.print(e);
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        return t;
    }

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc)
        {
            Log.i("**************************************", "Location changed");
            if(isBetterLocation(loc, previousBestLocation)) {
                String newLocation = "Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + " and Long: " + loc.getLongitude();
               i = new Intent("LOCATION_CHANGED");
                i.putExtra("location", newLocation);
                sendBroadcast(i);
            }
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }


        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And I have received broadcasted intent in `MainActivity` as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView txt_location;    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt_location = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.current_location);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }    

    public class LocationBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
            txt_location.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("location"));
        }
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

As you can see, it is not showing any location updates. Logcat isn't showing any errors. Can anyone please guide me what is the mistake?

Comment: @Leo hey, it isn't duplicate...I have seen it..My problem is different.

Comment: oops, you're right. I have no idea why I completely disregarded the part were you say "continuously"

Comment: @Leo ok..no problem:-)

Answer (score 4):

Create a `BroadcastReceiver` in the `MainActivity` like

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context appContext, Intent intent) {
        .......
        //get location from Service and create Method for set location on textview txt_location

    }
};
```

`registerReceiver` in `onResume` of `MainActivity`

```
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(GET_LOCATION));
```

and declare this in starting `MainActivity`

```
private static final String GET_LOCATION = "com.pkg.location";
```

and in your service pass your location as a broadcase

```
Intent intent = new Intent(GET_LOCATION);
intent.putExtra("location", "your_location_got_from_service");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and dont forget to `unregisterReceiver` in `MainActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```

Comment: should I delete the class LocationBroadcast which extends BroadcastReciever?

Comment: private static final String GET_LOCATION = "com.pkg.location"; I can't understand this line? why did you named package as this?

Comment: just an example you can change it

Comment: Hi..I have just updated the question...It isn't working..Please help me.

Comment: registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(GET_LOCATION));

Answer (score 3):

You can use BroadcastReceiver to receive the event of your **LOCATION_CHANGED**, and update the `TextView` from its `onReceive` method:

In your activity:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location_text);  //global variable

registerReceiver(locationChangedReceiver, new IntentFilter("LOCATION_CHANGED"));

//your receiver class as inner class of activity.
private BroadcastReceiver locationChangedReceiver= new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        textView.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("location"));

    }
};
```

In your service, you can simply broadcast for "LOCATION_CHANGED", and pass String location as intent's extra argument.

```
String newLocation = "Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + " and Long: " + loc.getLongitude();
Intent i = new Intent("LOCATION_CHANGED");
i.putExtra("location", newLocation);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

If you want to keep a separate receiver class (not in activity), you can use your context to update views like this:

```
public class LocationBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) ctx.findViewById(R.id.location_text);
        textView.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("location"));
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i got error on last line of your code..at ctx.findViewById(R.id.location_text); showing that findViewById can not be resolved

Comment: Hi..Are you there sir? I have just updated the question...It isn't working..Please help me.